# Can I apply for an Irish visa if I have been deported from Ireland?

Tags: visas

I hold a Chinese passport and have both Schengen tourist visa and UK student visa.

I thought I can use those visas to go to  Ireland for travel. Unfortunately the border police deported me because I have not a valid Irish visa.

I decide to apply for a Irish visa when I come back to London.  Does having an Irish refusal entry record affect the result of the application?

Comment: They refused you entry due to lack of a needed visa, which is different than deportation. Simply apply for a visa to fulfill the entry condition. After a deportation such an application would probably not be granted. For a one time refusal, if all other conditions are fulfilled, very likely it will be granted.

Comment: What do you mean by "deportation"? Where was you checked and what documents were you given?

Comment: If you had been deported, it might very well affect visa applications, but you haven't been.